# How can I know which apps are currently connecting to the Internet?

Tags: sync

I have a Samsung Spica running Eclair (rooted). I've noticed on a number of occasions that inspite of the Autosync option **turned off**, the sync icon appears in the notification bar. By default, Gmail, Calendar & Contacts are set to sync whenever the Autosync option is turned on.

I don't use any scheduler app like Locale or Tasker.

Is there an app or some way to see which app is connecting to the Internet at any given time? Or can someone verify if this sort of behaviour of the sync icon appearing is normal?

Comment: Why don't you disable wifi/3g when you don't need it?

Comment: @balki To receive notifications, maybe?

Comment: You may like to see the [answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/160408/131553) which does this job and more, in terms of tracking real time app data usage

Comment: Related: [How to view network traffic requested by a specific app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204022/218526)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[OS Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor&hl=en) does that. Shows the name of the app, and the IP address of the connection (including a WHOIS with a map when you click on it).

EDIT: I should mention that the sync icon TYPICALLY indicates a system-level sync. Do you have every item (GMail, Contacts, Calendar, Facebook) explicitly turned off in the settings?

Comment: No...in fact, I use Gmail, Calendar & Contacts (no FB) to sync. But my understanding was that they wouldn't and shouldn't, unless Auto Sync is enabled or a manual sync is performed from within the Accounts section of the settings.

I'll try OS Monitor for some time before reporting back. Thanks!

Comment: @Sparx: The system-level Sync option is voluntary, not mandatory, apps may ignore it and poorly written apps may still sync even though you have turned off system-level Sync.

Comment: True...I've seen this occur. But thanks to OS Monitor, one is aware of which apps are attempting to connect.

Comment: I'm using redmi note 4X running MIUI 9 and it says my device is not compatible with _this_ version. Any pointers?

Comment: OS Monitor works only with Android 6 and below.  We're on version 10 now.

Answer (score 4):

[PhoneUsage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jupiterapps.phoneusage) keeps track of how much data you use each day, and gives a nice display of which apps used how much data.

Here is an example of what mine looked like this month:

[image]
<sup>Click to enlarge the Image</sup>

NOTE: It only starts tracking after installation.

Comment: Does it show usage in real time? Coz that's what the question is about.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [SPB Wireless Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spb.wirelessmonitor). It can give you reports by date range of which apps have used data, how much data they've used, and breaks it down so you can see wifi data vs. data-plan data.

There's a new app, [My Data Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm), which costs a fraction.

You can check that out as well. It does basically the same thing, though will also show you roaming data. Also, this one allows you to enter a monthly start date so you can align its data tracking with your billing cycle.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that no one has mentioned [Onavo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onavo.android.onavoid&hl=en)!
It works great! And a quite intuitive interface too!

**UPDATE:** Seems Onavo pulled data manager app from app store and created a VPN + Data Manager app. You can find it [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.onavo.spaceship). I haven't used it so don't know how helpful it is.

Comment: It seems to track only mobile data, not WiFi.

Comment: Google play store says "item not found".

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ updated the link

Answer (score 1):

Use [Netlive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.richardlucasapps.netlive&hl=en). It'll give you stats of data usage by apps in real-time.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called [Network Connections on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antispycell.connmonitor) also with Live Capture for example.

Comment: You could provide a link to the app in question, so readers could find the app directly.

Answer (score 0):

Cm data manager

Is the best apps shows you wish apps are connected even system maybe viros to detect

And can block any apps data use

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I use this application from Google Play called [AndroidBooster from NetQuin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netqin.mobileguard). This app gives you with a list of apps that maybe using you internet.

Once installed, go to Utilities Tab > Network Manager and there you will see list of applications that maybe using the internet. It will on tell you if an app can use internet. It does not tell how much data each app uses or have used.
Good luck