# How do I determine which app is syncing?

Tags: sync, resource-monitoring

I frequently see the syncing icon in my notification bar, but every once in a while it gets stuck there, perpetually syncing something.  I have tons of apps that do background syncs.  How can I see which app is performing a sync at any given time?

**Edit:**

The duplicate question linked below suggested OS Monitor however I have tried that app and it doesn't tell me which app is syncing.  Under the Connections Tab it lists System, Android System, Lookout and OSMonitor.  I tested it by syncing a number of apps (google apps like Reader and non-google apps like Evernote and Got To Do and it didn't show them.  I thought it might be an issue with those connections completing in the time it took me to switch back to OS Monitor but then I tried streaming some audio and it didn't seem to recognize that connection even though it was actively streaming.

On a more general note, I have found that "Monitor" apps are not very effective because they usually only monitor the present time which is indicitive of how your phone is running with the Monitor app open, not how it was acting prior to.  For example, when trying to identify performance bottlenecks, when I open the monitor app it identifies itself as the highest resource hog.

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I know which apps are currently connecting to the Internet?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3493/how-can-i-know-which-apps-are-currently-connecting-to-the-internet)

Comment: Perhaps the answer to this question may help - http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3493/how-can-i-know-which-apps-are-currently-connecting-to-the-internet

Comment: Thanks but that does not help.  I have already tried OS Monitor and it does not tell me which app is syncing and furthermore it doesn't accurately tell me which apps are using network data.

Comment: Accounts and Sync will show you what account is syncing. and if you go in to that, it will show you what "service" in the app is syncing.

Answer (score 3):

When you go in to accounts and sync. It is going to show which account is currently syncing. Then from there, you can go in to the account and you will see what type of sync is happening.

It will show, for example, that "Reader" is syncing. So Google Reader is the App that is syncing. Or it will Show "Gmail" is syncing.

Those would be the apps that are syncing. I don't think just any app can trigger a sync for some other app. Like Reader shouldn't be able to trigger a sync for Picasa Images. But really, even if they can trigger other apps to sync, it is still the original app that is performing the sync. Only the twitter app is going to sync "twitter data and contacts", and only the Gmail app is going to sync your Gmail.

Comment: This is no longer true in Gingerbread on the Droid X.  It did work in Froyo on the Droid X.

Comment: Mine still shows what services are syncing when I go in there on Gingerbread.