# How to know which applications are using the Internet?

Tags: applications, internet, bandwidth

I use a lot of applications on my Android phone, and I'd like to know which applications are using the Internet at a given point of time, and also the bandwidth consumed by each one of them. [This question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3493/) from 2010 suggested [OS Monitor](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-eolwral-osmonitor-xxxt.aspx), but it's not currently available for download.

Is there a way to accomplish this?