# How can I see how much internet bandwidth each process is using at the moment?

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, bandwidth

On Android, I have a nice [Xposed module](http://repo.xposed.info/module/tw.fatminmin.xposed.networkspeedindicator) which shows me the current internet usage, but for the whole system, not per app:

[image]

On my desktop computer I have this [expandable panel item](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) which shows me exactly which apps are using the internet connection at any given moment. It also shows me exactly how much they're uploading and downloading per second right now, on a *per app* basis. The UI looks like this:

[image]

So I wonder if this is possible on Android as well. I'm asking for a *per app* metric of up/down usage right now, as in the above screenshot from my desktop computer.

Is there any way to get that?

To clarify even more, I'm asking for **current** speed, not past, accumulated usage.

Solutions that require root access and Xposed Framework are welcome.

Comment: Related: [How to view network traffic requested by a specific app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204022/218526)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Simple System Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dp.sysmonitor.app) does that

Relevant feature from app description

> View list of active apps and processes and their CPU usage, RAM usage, **network activity**, PID and UID.

If you monitor the *Active Processes* tab you can see the change in data usage. You can order the view based on parameters as shown in the second screen shot. The default update interval in settings is 3 seconds which can be varied as per need. If you worried about battery consumption , you can *pause* the app from the menu option on top left

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's Feb 2024, I've tried the Simple System Monitor app from the accepted answer and the app didn't have bandwidth information that is shown on the screenshot. The 'active processes' tab is there, but with no bandwidth info.

So the app that helped me answer the question "What app is using a lot of Wi-Fi bandwidth behind my back?": [GlassWire Data Usage Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.glasswire.android)