# Can we see what apps are logged in?

Tags: applications

I think that the question is different to What Apps Are Running, I want to know what apps are logged in.

I discovered that couchsurfing, despite not using it for months was logged in, eBay was, likely others. I don't particularly want them collecting data.

Short of opening each app and checking, is there a system way to do this?

Comment: See this [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/160408/131553) for a more versatile app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of *system level* approach but this app gives you a view [OS Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor). There may be other apps too

> It offers the following information.
>
> - Processes - monitor all processes.
> - **Connections - display every network connection.**
> - Misc - monitor battery, processors, network interfaces and file system.
> - Messages - search dmesg or logcat in real-time.

Snapshot from the app on my device below

[image]