# How can I see which websites use up most of my foreground data?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, browser, chrome-for-android, mobile-data

Every month I use up most of my mobile data in Chrome. This is the foreground data, not background data, so the data saver settings don't do much.

My plan is to avoid those websites that use up most of my data. But to do so I need to find out which websites do so.

My mobile data usage only charts per app, and while I know it's chrome, I have no indication which website is most to blame.

Is there a way of recording this, either in the browser via flags/policy/settings or on a system level (system settings or another application)? I've used VPN apps as a  firewall previously but they ended up using a lot of battery.

How can I track website data usage on chrome?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get a granular record (I may be wrong) but you can try the app mentioned [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/160408/131553) and to see the network usage opening a single chrome site at a time. That could possibly help you in identifying data hogging sites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I discussed a similar issue here: [Android app to show what apps/processes are currently using data](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/48445/29904). The same workaround is applicable in this case too.

I will focus on this specific part however:

> How can I track website data usage on chrome?

It is still possible using the mentioned tool: [Network Connections](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antispycell.connmonitor)

- To get website specific usage just open the app and navigate to *Current Connections* Tab.
- The log is given in two formats i.e IP address or hostaname. If you want the Ip address resolved to hostname simply tap, **Resolve IPs to Hostname option**.

  It should appear like this:

  [image]

*I produced this log, when I was browsing StackExchange website, and from the screenshot you can see it gives the data usage associated with the website an if you open another website it also shows data usage specific to that hostname and sub-hostname associated to that particular website.*

Only part that I am not sure is giving a very finer log on per website basis that can be stored as a seperate log, AFAICT you could periodically start live capture of traffic and see the sites which generate a lot of data usage.

Comment: Do your know why it wouldn't show the amount of data sent and received? All I see is the connection status (TCP established etc.)

Comment: You mean on yourdevice, can start a live traffic capture?

Comment: Yes, I can follow the steps in your post but I don't get the same result.