# How to log the source of a freeze?

Tags: performance, system-freeze

Since some time my Samsung Galaxy 9+ sometimes freezes.

I have the impression that this is somehow related to Chome but I am not sure (maybe it is just because I spend there more time than on other apps and statistically am on it when the freeze happens)

This is a total freeze for ~10 seconds, then everything works again. The screen is on, the phone is just not reactive.

Would there be a way to monitor the phone and pin point the app which makes the phone freeze? (due to overuse of some resources)

Comment: Try to run [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dp.sysmonitor.app) and see which are the top two or three processes running at the time of freeze

Comment: Related to the app recommended https://android.stackexchange.com/a/160408/131553