# Samsung a32 5g - Does auto sync take up a significant amount of data?

Tags: sync, gmail, mobile-data

I am synced to 5 gmail accounts, 1 facebook account, office, onedrive, reddit, soundcloud samsung account, whatsapp and 2 twitter accounts.

I only really receive a decent amount of emails from two of my gmail accounts, and some notifications some reddit. I notice I still get notifications from reddit regardless of having auto sync on, as well as whatsapp, twitter, and facebook. I don't use soundcloud often so I'm not sure what I would even use data from auto-sync.

In general does auto-sync only really take up data if I get emails, and other apps that normally send notifications are not part of auto-sync? If I got about 100 emails on mobile data with auto-sync on, about how much data would that take up? What other usage auto-sync uses mobile data other than what I mentioned?

Comment: Use app mentioned [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/160408/131553), enable sync and find out for yourself, what it takes on your device //I don't think you can get a general answer on this

Comment: Also see this https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203868/131553

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out sometime :)

Comment: @beeshyams
Also do you know if allowing background data and allow background activity are necessary for Gmail to send notifications on mobile data or is it just auto sync that is required? If not, what is the purpose of enabling these two options?

Comment: AFAIK, they are needed for you to receive mails and show you notifications pertaining to those mails.

Comment: Thank you, it seems background activity doesn't do much at all, however background data usage is required to get notifications on mobile.

Comment: Background activity for one generates wake locks to keep the app alive though it's in background //maybe other things too

Comment: Thanks, from what I know it's useless for gmail if all you want from it is notifications and opening it. Might only be useful for making it open faster and that's it.

Comment: Nope never mind my bad, you do need to allow it in the background for notifications. Not sure why things like twitter and reddit don't.